# How to estimate the Scoring Scheme in Pairwise Alignment

Tags: sequence, dynamic-programming, bioinformatics, text-alignment

I'm not specialist in bioinformatics. I want to align two nucleotide sequences using a global alignment method. Each sequence is a combinations of the {A,C,T,G} letters.

The problem is that I don't know how to choose the best scoring scheme (substations and gap penalties).

Currently, I'm using the values +1,-1,-2 for match , mismatch and gap penalty. And I'm aware that ; the number of transitions in human DNA is larger than the number of transversions.

My question is how to estimate the penalties for (match , mismatch and gap) based on my dataset. Is there any statistical model can help?

Answer (score 0):

If we need to answer to this question we need to know the dataset well and your scope exactly,but generally for match/mismatch we may represent as  +1/-1 this does not include (transversion and transition).

For I advice you to take a look on this [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Models_of_DNA_evolution) and [Kimura](http://www.megasoftware.net/mega4/WebHelp/part_iv___evolutionary_analysis/computing_evolutionary_distances/distance_models/nucleotide_substitution_models/hc_kimura_2_parameter_distance.htm)

Finally for penalty, you may use "low, medium, and high" penalty according to the divergent the sequences,I mean If the organisms is closely related then you may use the low gap penalty, and the high penalty for the more divergent organisms, so the gap penalty depends on how divergent the sequences are that you are aligning.

If we need to know if the sequences is divergent or not, as I said it's depends and different according to your data, but you may take a look on these examples about some sequences : [link1](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/sequences_series_approx_calc/seq-conv-diverg/v/convergent-and-divergent-sequences), [link2](https://www.dnastar.com/megalign_help/index.html#!Documents/calculationofdiverge.htm), [link3](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/Sequences.aspx), [link4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9K1xx6wfN-U), and [link5](http://darwin.eeb.uconn.edu/simulations/dna-dist.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but what do you mean of "divergent the sequences" and how can we calculate that?

Comment: Thank you, I meant, how we calculate the  divergent of the sequences ? statistically?

Comment: Check the answer again please